# jquery get fragment gets whole page

Tags: jquery, ajax

anybody has experienced this, what may be wrong?
basically I use get ended with space followed by id/hash of element on other page but jquery always loads whole page....

snippet here:

```
var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
url = url+' #detail';
console.log('LOADING '+url);
$.get( url, function(dt){datadetail = dt;} );
$('#result').append(datadetail);
```

there is element with id="detail" on the other page, both pages on same domain, yet it always loads whole page instead of fragment... what may be wrong?

Comment: the console.log in snippet prints url as expected, so its url of the other page followed by space and the hashtag

Comment: trying using load, always get a function not defined error, grrr. I need to load it to variable, not element, as I'd like to load a page fragment using the colorbox plugin

Comment: `load()` replaces everything in the container, it doesn't append and it doesn't get the data in a variable, so it's probably not very usable here? Also note that your code has asynchronocity issues as you're trying to append outside the callback.

Answer (score 3):

`$.get` doesn't work that way, there is no filter. Only [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) has that, and it still gets everything, it just filters before outputting.

What you want is something like

```
var url = $(this).attr('href'); 

$.get( url, function(dt){
    var datadetail = $('<div />', {html : dt}).find('#detail');
    $('#result').append(datadetail);
});
```